# Sumar datos de tablas ID por ID en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas en la que registro datos estadisticos de baseball del año 2016 y otra del año 2017.

No he podido formular un Query que me sume las estadisticas de los 2 años de cada jugador y me lo muestre de la misma manera en que se muestran en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, porque en esa le especifico el ID, pero en esta quiero que me tire todos los datos, o que me muestre todos los ID.

Comment: De esa manera, solo me muestra 1 jugador.

Comment: Como le podria decir al WHERE que me tire todos los datos? **Where id = **

Comment: No , si tu igualas a un ID, siempre te va a traer ese. Pon en el SELECT el ID, no en el WHERE. `SELECT id,sum(CA) totalCA FROM
(
    SELECT id,CA 
    FROM 2016_table
    union all
    SELECT id,CA
    FROM 2017_table
) t
GROUP BY id`

Lee [Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) - Se puede traducir muy bien, arriba a la derecha

Comment: @FedericoMadoery gracias por tu ayuda, no se como agradecerte.  Gracias por ayudarme con el rompecabezas que tenia.

Answer (score 0):

Para relacionar tablas podrias usar inner join

```
   SELECT tabla.dato,
   ([columna 1] + [columna 2] as tablas_totales
   FROM
   (SELECT [dato],
   sum([campo1]) AS "columna 1"
   FROM [dbo].[Ejemplo1]
   GROUP BY dato) as tabla_1
   inner join
   (SELECT [dato],
   sum([campo2]) AS "columna 2"
   FROM [dbo].[Ejemplo2]
   GROUP BY dato) as tabla_2
   on tabla_1.dato = tabla_2.dato
   ORDER BY tabla_1.dato
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacer la consulta a la base de datos algo asi

> SELECT ID, AÑO, NOMBRE, SUM(ATRIBUTO1), SUM(ATRIBUTO2), SUM... FROM (TABLA1) INNER JOIN
>   (TABLA2) USING (ID) WHERE AÑO >= (año_inicial) AND AÑO <= (año_final)
>   GROUP BY (ID)

las variables año_final y año_inicial las especificas vos.